# Iteration within foreach loop

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, foreach

I try to iterate an array within a foreach loop with the following code:

```
$array = array(
  'param1_1'  => 'foo',
  'param1_2'  => 'foo_bar',
  'param1_3'  => 'foo',
  'param1_4'  => 'foobar1',
  'param1_5'  => 'foo',
  'param1_6'  => 'foo_bar',
  'param1_7'  => 'foobar',
);
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
  $group[$key] = array(
    'content'  => $value != 'foo_bar' ? $output->{$value}($key) : $output->{$value}($key, '', '', '', '', 'px'),
    'required' => 0,
  );    
}
```

I try to get an HTML output build on bootstrap.
This foreach loop does not work like I wish

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
  $group[$key] = array(
    'content'  => '<div class="row">
                   <div class="col-sm-3">' . $value != 'foobar' ? $output->{$value}($key) : $output->{$value}($key, '', '', '', '', 'px') . '</div>
                    </div>',
  'required' => 0,
  );    
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `does not work like I wish` And we should guess how you wish?

Comment: Post `$output` class please.

Comment: @user1286819 what output you want.

Comment: I would like to get this by the foreach loop: take 3 array keys and do the output. take the next 3 array keys and do the next output and so on

Answer (score 0):

```
      <?php
      foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
          $group[$key] = array(
            'content'  => '<div class="col-sm-3">' . $value != 'foobar' ? $output->{$value}($key) : $output->{$value}($key, '', '', '', '', 'px') . '</div>',
          'required' => 0,
          );    
        }
    ?>
```

Remove the `<div class="row"></div>` .I think this is what you have been doing wrong.